# QueryDSL - Avoid NPE when date is null

Tags: java, date, querydsl

I have a query that has the following `where` clause:

`.where(table.lastupdated.after(date))`

Where the `date` is just a Timestamp. However, `date` can be `null`. If I pass a `null` date I will get an NPE. How can I avoid this?

In the case where the `date` is `null`, I want the query to execute as if the `where` clause above does not exist. In other words, to query the entire table regardless of the `lastupdated` field.

The query is rather large, I'd rather not create two queries (one with date check and the other without). I'm looking for something more succint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first build your query and then execute it.

```
if (date != null) {
    query = query.where(table.lastUpdated.after(date));
}

repository.findOne(query);
```

No need to make 2 different queries.

Comment: I see what you're doing

Comment: The original query will be without where clause appended to it. But still good.

Comment: Cool that you copied my answer, including the formating :)

Comment: There is only one proper way to format those 3 lines of code :)

Answer (score 2):

You're only option is to handle `null` here in Java yourself:

```
if (date != null) {
    query.where(table.lastUpdated.after(date);
}
```

The problem is that a Java `null` is not equivalent to a SQL `NULL`. For example, `WHERE lastUpdated > null` will return an empty result set in SQL, because any operation against `NULL` yields `NULL` which itself is falsey.

QueryDSL guards you against this unexpected behaviour by enforcing users to implement their own null handling. If you actually need a null expression in your query, then you should use `Expressions.nullExpression()`.